# How to transform a Java object into JSON tree format with jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I want to use Jackson to convert a Java object into JSON format. I have a class which looks pretty much the following structure

```
public Class Event
{
  String type;
  String timestamp;
  String hostname;
  String service;
  Payload payload;
}
```

I have the getters and setters for the above fields and also the getters/setters in Payload class.

Here is the json format, i want

```
{
    "type":"end",
    "time":"2016-08-01 11:11:11:111",
    "origin":{
        "hostname":"<hostname>",
        "service":"<service>"
    },
    "version":"1.0"
    "data":{ .... }
}
```

I can't seem to find a jackson way to get the above format, don't know how to put the whole payload object in "data" node and how to put the hostname, service in the "origin" node.

Comment: Hi, your json property names do not match your java property names (on purpose?) - also you will need to add the payload class so we know how the nested version looks like (e.g. is orign => payload?)

Comment: Hi, origin isn't payload, it is a part of the header wrapping the hostname and service field, "data" is supposed to wrap the payload

Answer (score 0):

from your question, this is one approach that should showcase on how to solve it. Since you only posted 1 class, I am changing the payload to be a map. It works the same way with other classes as well.

Consider this example:

```
public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        Event e = new Event();
        e.type="end";
        e.service="<service>";
        e.hostname = "<hostname>";
        e.timestamp = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
        Map<String,String> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put("param1", "xyz");
        e.payload = payload;

        String writeValueAsString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(e);
        System.out.println(writeValueAsString);
    }



    public static class Event {
        @JsonProperty
        String type;
        @JsonProperty("time")
        String timestamp;
        @JsonIgnore
        String hostname;
        @JsonIgnore
        String service;
        @JsonProperty("data")
        Map<String, String> payload;

        @JsonProperty("origin")
        Map<String,String> getOrigin() {
            Map<String,String> tmp = new HashMap<>();
            tmp.put("hostname", hostname);
            tmp.put("service", service);
            return tmp;
        }

        @JsonProperty("version")
        private String getVersion() {
            return "1.0";
        }
    }


}
```

I annotate the Event class with the necessary properties I want and the names they should have. Since you want the hostname and service to be in a nested setting and not create a new object for it (a new object would be easier as you could just have that serialised), I ignore those and instead use a getter to create the necessary structure as a map.

The output is:

```
{
"type":"end",
"time":"2016-08-19T16:45:18.072",
"data":{"param1":"xyz"},
"origin":{
  "hostname":"<hostname>",
  "service":"<service>"
},
"version":"1.0"
}
```

Regads,

Artur